# Qt/Qml: Custom widget -- cannot set "width" property as it is readonly

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I have created a custom widget called `OpenGLWidget` which I have registered with the `qmlRegisterType` function.

Nested inside the Qml file, I have this:

```
OpenGLWidget {
  id: glwidget
  width: parent.width
}
```

My app dies saying that `width` is a readonly property.

I have also tried adding this line to the `OpenGLWidget` header file:

```
Q_PROPERTY(int width READ width WRITE setWidth NOTIFY widthChanged)
```

(However, even if these methods are not there, the code still compiles -- why?)

Anyway, it seems to me like `Q_PROPERTY` is used if you want to add your own custom properties, but properties like `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`, etc (which are all readonly) ought to be built-in, no?

EDIT: `OpenGLWidget` header file upon request.

```
#ifndef OPENGLWIDGET_H
#define OPENGLWIDGET_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QGLWidget>

class OpenGLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_PROPERTY(int width READ width WRITE setWidth NOTIFY widthChanged)

public:
    OpenGLWidget();

    void setWidth(int width) { resizeGL(width, this->geometry().height()); }
    void widthChanged(int width) { }

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);
};

#endif // OPENGLWIDGET_H
```

Comment: Question needs at least the source code (.h file) of OpenGLWidget class definition (possibly with irrelevant private members stripped if there are a lot).

Comment: @hyde Fixed, see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro. This causes the Qt meta object system to think of it as the closest superclass where the macro was defined, missing your method overrides.

Add `Q_OBJECT` line before the `Q_PROPERTY` line (it is needed so that the build system knows to run *moc* for this class). Then run *qmake* manually (eg. from Qt Creator build menu), because this change isn't picked up automatically so Makefiles aren't updated automatically.

It is a good idea to use Qt Creator new class wizard to add classes to a project, to avoid easy mistakes like this.

Comment: OK, seems like a plausible explaination, thanks! I will accept this answer as soon as I try it out. A couple of questions though: 1) another guy told me that I should use `QQuickFramebufferObject` instead, and not a widget, since this is Qt Quick. Should I? 2) I just want to forward all `width` calls to the base class' methods, is this possible?

Comment: @Tobias 1. If you don't have an actual reason  to have it, try to remove widgets module from any Qt Quick application (just to make it slightly smaller and simpler and build faster etc), and just have gui module. So yeah. 2. If you don't override a method, base class method will be called. If you want to override but call base class method from it, the C++ syntax for that is is *BaseClass::method();*